# How to plot line per category in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out if there is some way to plot a line per category in highcharts, i've tried for a while following this [doc](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines) and my current chart looks like this:

[image: image of my current chart]

What i want to achieve is something like this:
[image: chart i'm trying to create]

with each line stoping on the next category, this way i can set "goals" per category.

My [code](https://jsfiddle.net/nqy8wdah/) so far

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
          text: null
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Population (millions)',
          align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
          overflow: 'justify'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          color: 'red',
          value: 300,
          width: 2
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Gastos',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2],
        color: '#f25a41'
      }, {
        name: 'Renda',
        data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6],
        color: '#5c90f9'
      }]
    });
```

Comment: can you explain more on "with each line stoping on the next category, this way i can set "goals" per category." ?

Comment: what I got is, you want to highlight some category in the form of red mark.

Comment: @TechnoCrat What i was trying to do was to use plotLine like it was suggesting a "goal to achieve" for each line: ex.: this month i spent 3000USD, my goal is to spend less than 3500USD, so a red mark will be placed at 3500... In the picture where it says Africa, America, Asia... will be something like House bills, Restaurants, Travels, etc.

Comment: Got it. d_paul has answered it nicely with demo and api reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create custom marker for each category using `Renderer.path()` function.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/809y2wcn/

Comment: Fantastic! That's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Cool! If you find it useful, please accept the answer and upvote it. Thanks.